# Live Wordpress wp-admin not showing template dropdown

Tags: wordpress

I am using the blankslate theme and used custom templates for my homepage. This all worked locally. Once I tried doing the same thing on my domain wp-admin the template dropdown does not show up. I tried several things I saw throughout the internet such as, switching themes then switching back to blankslate, making sure my index.php and styles.css were in the right directory, template is in the correct directory. I am at a loss everything is set up, just need the template dropdown to show to connect my template to the particular page.

Comment: Which version you are using in live site.

Comment: Please see here https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/42573

Comment: @UditRawat I am using the latest version 4.9.1

Comment: I believe you know how to create custom template in WordPress. And let assume you done all with this but still you facing that bug.

then it's a template cache bug. Find patch file from above link and apply that to your wordpress.

Comment: I found the patch file, where do I add this https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/42573/42573.5.patch

It is clear it is a caching issue as in my localhost the new caching feature doesn't exist but it does on my live wordpress @UditRawat

Comment: You can use git apply patch command or open patch file and manually change the code.